# I am not able to run app in mobile (android) REACT NATIVE

Tags: android, reactjs, debugging, native

I am not able to run app in mobile (android)
I have done the following:
1)changed data cables -on and off usb debugging
2)changes mobiles
3)adb devices doesnot show my mobile first, so then i off and on usb debugging..Then when i run adb devices i get the mobile in it.. So i used to run: react-native run-android..

Emulator not found  because i closed the emulator...  but i have connected my mobile  still why???

got wasted lot of my time in this issue...  so thankful if anyone can help me

Comment: Just run the app from android studio instead - Never fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below

> npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

**Please read this document follow this step I hope it will be helpful for him.
**

https://aboutreact.com/how-to-run-react-native-app-on-real-device-android/

Answer (score 0):

use command
`npm cache clean --force` to clean cache
then after run
`npx react-native run-android`

read this official document of react native it will surely help you
https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device